# Visualizing vessel data / tracks on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, visualization, gpx, nmea

I'm currently working on a Web project, which should display tracks of vessels (similar to Marinetraffic).

I have the data of the past track of the vessel (LAT/LON; Course, Speed) saved in a NMEA-file.

Here is the approach that Marinetraffic.com took to visualize its track data:
[image: Track visualization on Marinetraffic.com]

For me it looks like the track visualization consists of points (the LAT / LON information, displayed here trough an arrow icon), which are connected trough lines.
**First question:** would you agree with that? Or should I approach differently?

Here is my current approach:
[image: Custom approach for visualization of NMEA data]

With the help of ChatGPT I've managed to build a simple HTML site with JS, which allows to upload a NMEA-file, which will then be displayed on a Leaflet-Map. **Second question:** Is Leaflet a good Maptool to use? Can you figure out, what Marinetraffic.com is using?

I'm displaying each geographic point I have on the map, and connecting them with a simple line, so they will make a track in the end.

My next step to get a similar view to the Marinetraffic-view, I've provided in the first screenshot. I want to swap the points with arrow-icons, which will be then roated to match the ship's course. However, this brings me into troubles because I have nearly 11400 geographic points displayed on the map. It will lag a lot. So I've looked how Marinetraffic solved this.
You can see it here: https://imgur.com/a/yzAEBEf

They use some kind of clustering (?). So if you zoom further away, less points will be displayed, so it doesnt have to load a massive amount of points. If you zoom in, more points will be displayed. I've tried to use the clustering of Leaflet, which works, but I dont like how it displays the amount of "clustered" in a colored circle.
**Third question:** I want that it exactly works like shown in the video. Any ideas how to implement that?

Thanks in advance.